# Do I need to exponentiate coefficients when I use Stata's logistic rather than Stata's logit?

Tags: regression, logistic, stata

I have a continuous variable and a binary variable. I am conducting logistic regression to see the relationship between them. Is it true that if I use the Stata command `logistic` rather than `logit`, Stata will exponentiate my coefficients for me into odds ratios? Does it also exponentiate the confidence intervals? How do I interpret them?

For example: if I'm looking at the relationship between height and gender and I get an exponentiated coefficient (so an odds ratio?) of 1.05, I am assuming that means that, say, males, are more likely to be taller than females (if females are coded as 0 and males as 1). Is that right?

Comment: In essence, yes: `the coefficients reported by `logistic` are by default those of `logit` exponentiated.

Comment: What happens when you read the help file for the `logistic` command, noting especially the `coef` option? What happens to the CIs when you use and do not use this option?

Comment: Okay I think it does thank you!